# testrpc alternative for running geth commands

Tags: ethereum

I'm trying to run [Etherex](https://github.com/etherex/etherex) project but that requires a lot of time to download the entire blockchain. Is there way I can simulate it using `testrpc`.

Here's the command that I use when using `geth`

`geth --testnet --rpc --rpccorsdomain http://localhost:8089`

Is there any way other than downloading the entire testnet blockchain to run the project. I've tried `testrpc` and `testrpc -p 8089` but both didn't work.